# Data Truncation com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Boa Noite.

Estou com um problema para persistir um objeto, o hibernate lança uma exceção dizendo que os dados são muito longos para a coluna "rua", do tipo String.

Seguem Pojos e DAO.

Endereço

```
@Embeddable
public class Endereco implements Serializable {

    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private String rua;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;

//Gets, Sets, Hash e Equals
```

Aluno

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Aluno", schema="IFBC")
public class Aluno implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idAluno;

    private int matricula;
    private int rg;

    private String nome;
    private String nomePai;
    private String nomeMae;
    private String naturalidade;
    private String orgaoExpedRG;
    private String obsAlergia;
    private String obsDoencaCronica;
    private String email;
    private String obs;
    private String cpf;

    private boolean possuiDoencaCronica;
    private boolean menorDeIdade;
    private boolean terminouCurso;
    private boolean possuiAlergia;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataInicioCurso;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataTerminoCurso;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataNascimento;

    private long telefone;

    private char sexo;

    @Embedded
    private Endereco endereco;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idTurma")
    private Turma turma;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idUsuario")
    private Usuario cadastrante; //Quem cadastrou

    private boolean formado;
```

DAO

```
public class Dao {

    private Session session;
    private Transaction transaction;

    public Dao() {

    }

    private void iniciarOperacao() {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    }

    private void terminarOperacao() {
        if(session != null) 
            session.close();
    }

    public boolean salvar(Object ob) {
        try {
            iniciarOperacao();
            session.saveOrUpdate(ob);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback(); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            terminarOperacao();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean excluir(Object obj) {
        try {
            iniciarOperacao();
            session.delete(obj);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            terminarOperacao();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public <T> T buscar(Class cls, int id) {
        T obj = null;

        try {
            iniciarOperacao();
            obj = (T) session.load(cls, id);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            terminarOperacao();
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public List listar(Class cls) {
        try {
            iniciarOperacao();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(cls);
            List list = criteria.list();
            transaction.commit();

            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            terminarOperacao();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [br.com.ifbc.model.pojo.Aluno]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at br.com.ifbc.control.dao.Dao.salvar(Dao.java:33)
    at br.com.ifbc.view.aluno.CadastrarAluno.btnCadastrarActionPerformed(CadastrarAluno.java:496)
    at br.com.ifbc.view.aluno.CadastrarAluno.access$000(CadastrarAluno.java:14)
    at br.com.ifbc.view.aluno.CadastrarAluno$1.actionPerformed(CadastrarAluno.java:109)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1655)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1607)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at br.com.ifbc.view.aluno.CadastrarAluno$5.run(CadastrarAluno.java:564)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'rua' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 75 more
```

O erro seria causado pelo `@Embeddable`? É a primeira vez que eu trabalho com isso.

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

A mensagem de erro não deixa dúvidas: o sistema está tentando inserir o registro no banco de dados, mas está enviando mais caracteres no campo `rua` do que cabe naquele campo.

Sua entidade não especifica o tamanho dos campos, então não tem como saber de cara qual o tamanho do campo `rua`. Também não sei se o sistema está gerando as tabelas com base no Hibernate ou se o banco é criado de alguma outra forma.

Se você usa o Hibernate para gerar as tabelas, sugiro fortemente que especifique o tamanho de cada coluna String. Exemplo:

```
@Column(length = 10) 
private String rua;
```

Caso contrário, todos os campos serão criados com o padrão de 255 caracteres, o que não fica legal numa modelagem.

Se, por outro lado, o banco é criado por outro processo, verifique na tabela ou script que cria a tabela qual o tamanho do campo `rua`.

Seria interessante adicionar anotações de validação dos dados para evitar esses erros estranhos. Veja, por exemplo, a documentação do [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/).

Por fim, verifique o tamanho da String que está sendo colocada no objeto `Endereco`. Provavelmente o sistema está permitindo o usuário digitar uma rua maior do que o tamanho da tabela, ou ainda está importando dados de algum lugar, como um arquivo text, e não verifica se o tamanho dos dados cabe na tabela.

Com todas essas informações, você terá que tomar a decisão de como resolver o problema, seja aumentando o tamanho do campo da tabela, cortando os dados digitados, limitando a entrada do usuário, etc.